# Calculating Mean for Multiple Rows in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I am trying to calculate a mean across a multiple number of attribute rows and have this value added to a new field that I have entered in the attribute table. I have an attribute table which has a number of different ecoregion types associated with them.

For example:

If I select "Arid Canyonlands" there are 3 attribute rows that are selected, each with their own "mean". I am trying to add a new field to the attribute table which will take the "mean" of these three and populate that value in the new field created. I could manually do it through an editing session and using a calculator but just wanted to know if there is an easier way to actually do it through field calculator?

Comment: Can you maybe post a screenshot how the table looks like?

Comment: I think you should use the Summary Statistics tool to calculate the mean.

Comment: Do you mean attribute column? Because taking the mean of several rows and sticking it into the column of one feature seems that it wouldn't be valid

Comment: When you say 'their own "mean" ', do you mean they already have a field named mean that you want to find the average of?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) tool to calculate the mean:

> Calculates summary statistics for field(s) in a table.
>
> ...
>
> The following statistical operations are available with this tool:
>   Sum, Mean, Maximum, Minimum, Range, Standard Deviation, Count, First,
>   and Last. The Median operation is not available.

Your "ecoregion type" field would be used as a case field:

> If a Case field is specified, statistics will be calculated separately
>   for each unique attribute value. The Output Table will contain only
>   one record if no Case field is specified. If one is specified, there
>   will be one record for each Case field value.